# How do I pass value via URL to thia PHP code.

Tags: php, rest

```
<?php 

require_once ("RestHandler.php");

$param="";
if(isset($_GET["param"]))
{
    $param = $_GET["param"];
}
//var_dump($param);

if(strpos($param,'studentlogin')!==false)   // for handling student login requests
{
    $param = explode("-",$param);       
    $param = explode(",",$param[1]);    
    $stuID = explode("=",$param[0]);
    $stuID = $stuID[1];
    $pass = explode("=",$param[1]);
    $pass = $pass[1];

    $restHandler = new RestHandler();
    $restHandler->checkStudentLogin($stuID,$pass);  
}
else if(strpos($param,'teacherslist')!==false)  
{
    $restHandler = new RestHandler();
    $restHandler->getTeachersList();    
}
else if(strpos($param,'questionslist')!==false) 
{
    $restHandler = new RestHandler();
    $restHandler->getQuestionsList();   
}
?>
```

This is the URL to get vale.

If I call this then it works properly.
http://localhost/xampp/api/index.php?param=questionslist

Response in JSON

[{"questionID":"1","statement":"How are you?"},{"questionID":"2","statement":"What is your name?"}]

However for log in (studentlogin) I can't figure out how to pass the value.

Comment: you want to pass this json in url?

Comment: No. I want to call studentlogin from URL

Comment: If I call index.php?param=questionslist from URL it returnes above JSON

Comment: Do you want to pass array in url?

Comment: I just need to get the studentlogin working. How do I pass ID & Pass?

Answer (score 0):

To pass values to via url, use whole details when click the link(submit or anything).

for example in your category:
 try this:

http://localhost/xampp/api/index.php?param=text-text=[studentID],text=[password]

remove [studentID] with ID and [password] with PASSWORD.
the student details was send via url. this may work.

Answer (score 0):

To pass array in url do like this

`http://localhost/path/index.php?param[]=param1&param[]=param2&param[key]=param3&name=name` etc.